# How to set finer-grain HDD Sleep settings in Mac OS 10.5?

Tags: mac-osx, mac, electrical-power, osx-leopard, mcx

Is it possible to specify how many minutes of inactivity Mac OS should wait before it sleeps hard disks? Is there a plist I can manually specify "60 minutes" or something?

The GUI gives you the option to "Put the Hard disk(s) to sleep when possible" in the Energy Saver preference pane, but I'd like to have it wait longer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do it from the command line (and doesn't require the Developer Tools installed - available on any 10.4 or 10.5 system) you're looking for a utility called `pmset` (power management set).

> disksleep - disk spindown timer; replaces 'spindown' argument in 10.4
>        (value in minutes, or 0 to disable)

eg. `sudo pmset -a disksleep 60`

As always for more check out the [man page](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html)

Comment: Thanks - argh, that's correct too! If I could pick multiple correct answers, I would.

Comment: @Adam, sorry since this requires no optional install, and can easily be rolled out to clients via SSH, I do think it's the winning answer.

Comment: username - hey, glad you got the answer you wanted and hopefully mine will be useful to someone else who finds this page!

Answer (score 5):

[CHUD tools](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/14358) contains [SpindownHD](http://lowendmac.com/musings/06/0217.html) which does what you want - look in:

```
/Developer/Applications/Performance Tools/CHUD/Hardware Tools
```

Comment: +1 for the nice application icon :-)

Comment: Cool, that should do the trick - CHUD Tools is part of Apple Developer Tools, which ships with every Mac. Also, I got off my rear end and googled: There is indeed a .plist setting stored in the root Library: /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.PowerManagement.plist

Comment: splattne - I think funky app icons are mandated as part of the Apple User Experience guidelines!

Answer (score 1):

You could try [SleepWatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/), an open source utility written by Bernhard Baehr, mentioned in this article:

[SleepWatcher - A utility to run tasks on sleep/wake](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20060908113605812)

Comment: It *monitors* sleep, wakeup and idleness of a *Mac* but (unless I'm missing something), SleepWatcher alone can not *control* sleep of a *hard disk drive* whilst the Mac is awake.